# How to make two update sites use the same features&plugins folder

Tags: eclipse, p2

Is there a way to maintain two different update sites/p2 repositories pointing to same folder having the plugins and features files?

I need to to maintain two sites: one for full fledged features list and one with limited features. So instead of maintaining duplicate copies of features and plugins, I want to refer it to full fledged site directory's features and plugins. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the deprecated repository format of the old Update Manager (-> `site.xml`), or would a current p2 repository format also be an option?

Comment: both works for me Berlis. Could you provide solutions for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The p2 artifact repository format allows to configure the location where it expects the artifacts through mapping rules. On of the default rules is

```
<rule filter='(&amp; (classifier=osgi.bundle))' output='${repoUrl}/plugins/${id}_${version}.jar'/>
```

So if for example your full repository is at http://example.org/full/ and the limited repository at http://example.org/limited/, you could have the limited repository point to the artifact files in the full repository with the following rule:

```
<rule filter='(&amp; (classifier=osgi.bundle))' output='${repoUrl}/../full/plugins/${id}_${version}.jar'/>
```

Just update all the rules in the same way, and it should work. Never tried this myself though.